# Ubuntu 11.10 then 12.04 then 60+ updates then boot only shows grub

Tags: 11.10, 12.04, nvidia, grub2, updates

I had 11.10 x64 installed on AMD 4core with NVidia card. I had problems changing screen resolution. I have just over-installed 12.04 x64. It went well. Screen resolution changes worked well. I ran diskutil(?) which said drive was good but grumbled about misaligned partitions of 1K & 3K. I then applies 60+ updates. It said it needed to restart. I press 'restart' screen button but it wouldn't restart. I pressed the H/W reset. It came up with GNU GRUB version 1.99, 3 lines help text and a GRUB prompt. I pressed H/W reset. Same GRUB prompt again.
How do I get the Ubuntu Desktop back? Thanks.

Comment: sorry - it insists on using tag 'grub2' instead of 'grub'

Comment: Grub 1.99 is Grub 2.

Comment: Well, I seem to have fixed it. I reinstalled, deleted swap space, added 3MB boot space(?), added swap back in, formatted OpSys partition & kept my big data partition. Applied updates and still boots okay. I guess some of those warnings (something like "no boot partition - you might have problems later") need to be made clearer.
(Hey! It lets me type all this and THEN says I can't answer my own Q. Duh!)

Answer (score 0):

Originally posted as a comment by [brewmanz](https://askubuntu.com/users/41461/brewmanz) (OP):

> I seem to have fixed it. I reinstalled, deleted swap space, added 3MB
>   boot space(?), added swap back in, formatted OpSys partition & kept my
>   big data partition. Applied updates and still boots okay. I guess some
>   of those warnings (something like "no boot partition - you might have
>   problems later") need to be made clearer.